# How to force an application to exit fullscreen in dwm?

Tags: window, dwm

I have an application that has no settings for fullscreen and is really annoying that it takes up all the screen. I am looking for a way that I can turn the application into a window.

Comment: If the application forces full screen, and has no ability to turn it off, then you are onto plums.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that `dwm` puts it in full screen to fill the tile, you can tell it in the `config.h` to be floating by default.

This is done in the `rules[]`:

```c
static const Rule rules[] = {
    /* class      instance    title       tags mask     isfloating   monitor */
    { "Gimp",     NULL,       NULL,       0,            1,           -1 },
    { "vlc",      NULL,       NULL,       0,            1,           -1 },
    { "feh",      NULL,       NULL,       0,            1,           -1 },
    { "Firefox",  NULL,       NULL,       1 << 8,       0,           -1 },
};
```

As you can see in my case `Gimp`, `vlc` and `feh` always open in floating mode (`isfl`), preventing them from filling the entire tile (and also, sliding the rest of the windows for me).

To find out the name that you should put in the first column (class) to tell the window manager which window it is, you can use the `xprop` tool. Example with `Gimp`:

```
$ xprop

[...]

WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW, WM_TAKE_FOCUS, _NET_WM_PING, _NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "gimp", "Gimp"
WM_ICON_NAME(STRING) = "GNU Image Manipulation Program"
_NET_WM_ICON_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "GNU Image Manipulation Program"
WM_NAME(STRING) = "GNU Image Manipulation Program"
_NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "GNU Image Manipulation Program"
```

Note that when running `xprop`, the cursor will become a trigger so that you can click on the target window, in this case the `Gimp` window.

The variable we are interested in in the output of `xprop` is `WM_CLASS(STRING)` which has the structure `WM_CLASS(STRING) = instance, class`. in the example above, that is `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "gimp", "Gimp"`  we need the `Class` (`Gimp`), which is what we will indicate in the `rules[]`.

Comment: What makes you think that the OP has access to the source code of the application (and the tools to recompile it)?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' in most cases `dwm` is built directly from the sources. It is the grace, in fact, of using `dwm`: it does not have configuration files like other tiled window managers (like `awesomewm`), but `dwm` is configured directly in code and for any modification, any, it must be recompiled. You can install `dwm` as a package, of course, but you will lose all configuration